# Custom Button that links to the Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, button

I need to create a Button for the Page Layout that links to the Visualforce Page (another page). It's for custom object. How can I do that? Can I use "Buttons, Links, and Actions" to open VF Page? Or I need to create another VF Page?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are plenty of references you can find via google that will help you with this as well, have you attempted to utilize any of those references, if so, which ones?

Comment: I have voted this question down specifically because it shows an astonishing lack of research. If you **[edit]** the post to demonstrate what effort you have made to at least look around, I will remove that vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Buttons, Links, and Actions. A Custom Button or Link with its Content Source set to Visualforce Page will work if the Standard Controller on the Visualforce Page is the same object as one the button or link is being created for. If the Visualforce Page uses a different Standard Controller, you can set Content Source to URL, and write a link to the Visualforce Page like:
https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/apex/yourVisualForcePageName